# Link a LightBox from a LightBox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, forms

I want to display HTML forms on LightBoxes. Each lightbox will be having a button. onClick of that button, a new LightBox should open up with a new HTML form in it. How do i do such kind of navigation. I have found the navigation between images but not for HTML form.

Answer (score 3):

You don´t need to open a new lightbox but load the content of the new form into the current one. Also, don´t capture the click event from the button, because if a user try to submit the form pressing enter from the keyboard, it won´t work. You can do something like this:

```
$('#lightbox form').submit(function(){

    // some validation logic can be here

    // load the form from another file
    $('#lightbox').load('step-two-form.html');

    // OR insert it from the same document
    $('#lightbox').html($('#step-two-form'));

    // and return false for avoid reload the page
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make two separate divs in the same lightbox content

```
<div class="lightbox">
  <div id="firstdiv">CONTENT 1 that contains a button to show #seconddiv and hide #firstdiv</div>
  <div id="seconddiv" class="hidden">CONTENT 2</div>
</div>
```

i have made something similar here
http://www.klein-associes.com/grand_public/#
click "Accès presse / Distributeur" then "s'inscrire" for a demo

```
$('#firstdiv #button1').click(function(){
        $('#firstdiv').fadeOut('fast',function(){
            $('#seconddiv').fadeIn('fast');
        });
});
```